# Unable to apply both scale and translate to a set of element

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm trying to create 7 svg elements separated each other using a array of numbers. the  thing is that I'm trying to apply a `transform:scale()` using css, and `transform:translate()` using d3js, but the result is not the expected. All the images are one on top of other.

this is the JS code:

```
var width = 512
var height = 700

var badge = '<path class="st0" d="M143.4,238.8v-179h-12.9c-0.1-11.5-9.4-20.8-20.9-20.8s-20.8,9.3-20.9,20.8H75.5v179h0.1l34,21.2l34-21.2H143.4L143.4,238.8z M109.6,79.5C98.8,79.5,90,70.7,90,59.9s8.8-19.6,19.6-19.6s19.6,8.8,19.6,19.6S120.4,79.5,109.6,79.5z"/>'

var distance = [40,80,120,160,200,240,280]

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height)

var badgeWrapper = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","badgeWrapper")

var badges = badgeWrapper.selectAll("g")
  .data(distance)
   .enter()
   .append("g")
   .attr("class","badges")  
   .html(badge)
   .attr("transform", function(d,i){
       return "translate(" + d + "," + 0 + ")"
   } )
```

and this is the SCC:

```
.badges{
    transform: scale(.5)
}
```

Comment: first observation: the code does not run. if you supply a `Run code snippet` we expect that it runs

Answer (score 1):

The `transform` in the CSS overrides the `transform` you set with JavaScript. That's the way CSS works, and it's proper expected.

An easy solution is using the paths' class in the CSS:

```
.st0 {
    transform: scale(.5)
}
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var width = 512
var height = 700

var badge = '<path class="st0" d="M143.4,238.8v-179h-12.9c-0.1-11.5-9.4-20.8-20.9-20.8s-20.8,9.3-20.9,20.8H75.5v179h0.1l34,21.2l34-21.2H143.4L143.4,238.8z M109.6,79.5C98.8,79.5,90,70.7,90,59.9s8.8-19.6,19.6-19.6s19.6,8.8,19.6,19.6S120.4,79.5,109.6,79.5z"/>'

var distance = [40, 80, 120, 160, 200, 240, 280]

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

var badgeWrapper = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "badgeWrapper")

var badges = badgeWrapper.selectAll("g")
  .data(distance)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "badges")
  .html(badge)
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + d + "," + 0 + ")"
  })
```

```css
.st0 {
  transform: scale(.5)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```